# I think i have a soft ban?

Tags: pokemon-go

I go to poke stops now and i cant get any items but can catch pokemon. I Loged into a diffrent accout and could get tose same pokestops. Did i get a soft ban? I did some soft gps hacking. That is all that happened

Comment: Is your backpack full of items?

Comment: No  it is not full

Comment: @Frank But he can catch Pokémon, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you've used GPS hacking in the past, it's likely you've been soft-banned or shadowbanned.

As of recently, Niantic has begun cracking down very heavily on cheaters of all types, so this is to be expected.

Just wait it out. If you still can't take any actions in-game after 72 hours or so, it's very likely you've been completely shadowbanned from the game.

Answer (score -2):

The GPS hacking could have thrown off the game. It could still think that you are too far away from the Pokestop to enteract with it. Try removing and redownloading the app. After removing whatever GPS trick you did.

If that does not work try reporting the issue in the apps settings tab